# How can I do a 5 min refresh and check if the txt is modified?

Tags: java, refresh

```
    while(true)
    {
                BasicFileAttributes attr2 = Files.readAttributes(txt_path_2, BasicFileAttributes.class);

                if(attr.lastModifiedTime() != attr2.lastModifiedTime())
                {
                    run.command(exe_path, txt_path);
                    run.start();
                }
                else
                    Thread.sleep(300000);
}
```

I did this, but it has eaten my whole computer, so I would like to write a block or function or whatewer, that checks, if the txt's last modification's date is changed, when it is, run the command again that is mentioned below, or if there's no modification, wait 5 minutes, then do a recheck.

Comment: What operating system will this be run on? It's possibly better to do a Cron job or schedule a job depending on which OS it is.

Comment: It will be running on Windows

Comment: You can use a scheduling library. Here's one: https://github.com/knowm/Sundial

Comment: Or if you want to  write it using java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Java allows you to have file system watch objects. They notify you on changes, instead of your code polling constantly.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I really didn't use them before, so I don't know where to begin